# OneNote REST API way too slow from a few day ago

Tags: onenote-api

I'm developing OneNote add-in which is using OneNote REST API.
It was slightly slow like taking 4-5 secs for an API call but it's way too slow like taking about 1 min for an call from yesterday.

Is it available to check something wrong with session id in response headers?

Request:

```
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages
```

Response:

```
Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Length →3614
Content-Type →application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
Date →Fri, 05 May 2017 04:53:29 GMT
Expires →-1
OData-Version →4.0
P3P →CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONi TELi CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDi OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR"
Pragma →no-cache
Preference-Applied →odata.include-annotations=*
Request-Processing-Time →63464.9347 ms
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
X-AuthenticatedUserId →ORGID-5461B3DB-4535-4C86-86B2-4171965B3B3D
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-CorrelationId →11d0dea1-bcf3-4658-a99b-f3af77d4e208
X-OfficeCluster →ause-000.apimonolith.onenote.com
X-OfficeFE →ApisFrontEnd_IN_2
X-OfficeVersion →16.0.8203.1550
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
X-RoutingCorrelationId →11d0dea1-bcf3-4658-a99b-f3af77d4e208
X-RoutingOfficeCluster →aue-000.reverseproxy.onenote.com
X-RoutingOfficeFE →ReverseProxyFrontEnd_IN_0
X-RoutingOfficeVersion →16.0.8204.1550
X-RoutingSessionId →67852300-b26a-4b5e-b830-8233acf7cadc
X-UserSessionId →67852300-b26a-4b5e-b830-8233acf7cadc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue!

If you're fetching OneNote pages, we generally recommend you do it by section or notebook instead of going through the top level collection. (E.g. GET sections/id/pages, notebooks/id/pages.

That said, we do have an issue in Production currently and are working to fix it. I will update this answer once resolved.

Comment: I feel it's back to similar response timing before but it starts giving me 500 error occasionally. I think you're still working on it but I want to let you know.

Comment: Hmm, no more 500 error and much faster now. Could you let me know if you have ETA?

Comment: This is resolved now - however we do strongly recommend fetching pages by section, as described above.